# JBoss Logging Configuration

Tags: logging, jboss

Is there a way to log specific logger to extra files or filter them when logging them to one file?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
      <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="WARN" />
        <formatter>
          <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}|%p|%t|%c{3}|%X{talo}|%m%n" />
        </formatter>
      </console-handler>
      <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
      <level name="TRACE"/>
        <formatter>
          <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}|%p|%t|%c{3}|%X{talo}|%m%n" />
        </formatter>
        <file
          relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir"
          path="server.log" />
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <append value="true" />
      </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
.
.
.
<root-logger>
    <level name="INFO" />
    <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE" />
      <handler name="FILE" />
    </handlers>
  </root-logger>
```

Currently the log file is getting flooded with WARNs etc. but for my use case I just want to display the hibernate logging.

Someone knows an approach to log hibernate to another file?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a perioodic-rotating-file-handler for your hibernate logs like:

```
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="HIBERNATE_LOG" autoflush="true">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <encoding value="UTF-8"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}|%p|%t|%c{3}|%X{talo}|%m%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="hibernate.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

and by logger define the handler like:

```
        <logger category="org.hibernate" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="HIBERNATE_LOG"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```